# SharePoint 2010 - Install Site Template using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, site-template, solution-package

I want to install site template in SharePoint 2010.
Basically i want to know how use install-spwebtemplate

wsp name : SPT_SiteTemplate.wsp
Name : SPT_SiteTemplate

Answer (score 1):

simply use [Add-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607552.aspx) and [Install-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607534.aspx).

if it's sandboxed, use instead [Add-SPUserSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607715.aspx) and [Install-SPUserSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607653.aspx).

Comment: with that i will have to activate in every site collection ? right ?
Then what is use of "install-spwebtemplate" cmdlet ?

Comment: a site template is used for new sites, not existings. I don't know what is the purpose of install-spwebtemplate

Comment: wondering if it's for legacy template support (as it's waiting for cab files)

Answer (score 1):

In SP2010 you can create web templates that can be deployed as either farm or site scoped features. `Install-spwebtemplate` is used for legacy templates so this is not what you should use (confusing, i know, especially since `get-spwebtemplates` works for showing installed templates)

If you create your custom web template as a sandboxed solution you can upload your solution to your site either using UI or by using `add-spusersolution`. Then you activate your solution and activate your feature, and your web template should now show when creating new sites.

Alternatively you can create a farm solution and a farm scoped feature. This is added using `Add-spsolution` and feature must me activated under farm solutions in central administration.

More info on creating custom web templates in visual studio [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119071517/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx).

Another option is to save your site as a template and upload that directly as with sandboxed solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Use "Get-Help install-spwebtemplate -full" command to find out usage of the command along with examples. This is true for any command in general.

Comment: patel: in this case, the help is useless; `The Install-SPWebTemplate cmdlet installs the given site template using the name provided (title) as the unique ID.` is not detailling what is the purpose of the command

Comment: If you understand the word "site template" its not that useless.

Comment: patel : i tried "Get-Help install-spwebtemplate -full" command but still not able to understand as rightly said by @steve b